# yaourt - unsupported package + AUR dependencies

Tags: archlinux

Пробую ставить [этот пакет](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=39165) из репозитория AUR. yaourt ругается:

> ( Unsupported package: Potentially dangerous ! ).

И все, ни слова что именно ему не понравилось. Майнтейнер пакету назначен. Ось x86_64, в PKGBUILD пакета такая вроде прописана. Ради интереса попробовал ставить оперу - все ровно. Собственно вопрос: как пофиксить, или на это сообщение вообще можно наплевать?

Вопрос второй: майнтенер случайно не сует зависимости в пакет каким-то рандомным образом. Как-то я не очень помню, чтобы asterisk обязательно зависел от postgres и sqlite. Да и speex вроде опциональный. Но это правда и не в Арче было. Склоняюсь компилить вручную.

Спасибо.

Update:С вопросом №1 кажется понятно. Ссылка на исходники пакета  - битая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забить. Это новый ёгурт так теперь ругается.